# Integrating Yubikey

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm planning on adding multi-factor authentication for the admins to a site I'm working on.  I decided to use Yubikey because of its simplicity, but am running into a roadblock on how to implement it.

Does anyone have a good example of how to save Yubikey, and how to verify an entered Yubikey (on login) is the saved Yubikey, and is a valid OTP?  I saw an entire site example on the Yubikey website, but I can't seem to find the bits I'm looking for.  I also don't want to use PEAR at all

Thanks

Comment: Might be important to note that this is [the only question tagged yubikey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yubikey). If you are stuck on something in particular, you might want to be specific and show code if you really want to get help, most people have probably never heard of this service, let alone integrated it with Codeigniter. What is this "roadblock" you allude to?

Comment: Yeah, I put it up hoping somebody had ran into this problem, and maybe had a class for it.  I realize this is the only question tagged Yubikey.  I can't seem to understand how to interact with their apis, but it looks like I'll need to figure it out.  And then I can post up my code, and the next guy looking will find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as Wesley pointed out, there doesn't seem to be a lot of knowledge about this product, so I took the time and modified the wonderful library put out on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/yubikey-val-server-php/) to work with codeigniter.

Sadly while doing this I had to remove the PEAR error messages, so errors now just return a generic FALSE.  The class is below, I hope somebody finds it useful

`libaries/yubikey.php`

```
<?php
  /**
   * Class for verifying Yubico One-Time-Passcodes
   *
   * @category    Auth
   * @package     Auth_Yubico
   * @author      Simon Josefsson <simon@yubico.com>, Olov Danielson <olov@yubico.com>, modified by mazzzzz to work with CodeIgniter
   * @copyright   2007, 2008, 2009, 2010 Yubico AB
   * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php New BSD License
   * @version     2.0
   * @link        http://www.yubico.com/
   */

/**
 * Class for verifying Yubico One-Time-Passcodes
 *
 * Simple example:
 * <code>
 * $otp = "ccbbddeertkrctjkkcglfndnlihhnvekchkcctif";
 * $SavedPrefix = "ccbbddeertkrct"; //Get using the below to lines that set $pkey.  This will verify the yubikey is the one you want aswell as a valid OTP
 *
 * # Generate a new id+key from https://api.yubico.com/get-api-key/ and put them into the yubikey config file
 * $yubi = $this->load->library('yubikey', array('https'=>1, 'verifyhttps'=>1));
 * $auth = $yubi->verify($otp);
 *
 * $pkey = $this->yubikey->parsePasswordOTP($this->input->post('key'));
 * $pkey = $pkey["prefix"];
 *
 *
 * if ($auth === FALSE || $pkey != $SavedPrefix) {
 *    print "<p>Not authenticated</p>";
 * } else {
 *    print "<p>You are authenticated!</p>";
 * }
 * </code>
 */
class yubikey
{
    /**#@+
     * @access private
     */

    /**
     * Yubico client ID
     * @var string
     */
    var $_id;

    /**
     * Yubico client key
     * @var string
     */
    var $_key;

    /**
     * URL part of validation server
     * @var string
     */
    var $_url;

    /**
     * List with URL part of validation servers
     * @var array
     */
    var $_url_list;

    /**
     * index to _url_list
     * @var int
     */
    var $_url_index;

    /**
     * Last query to server
     * @var string
     */
    var $_lastquery;

    /**
     * Response from server
     * @var string
     */
    var $_response;

    /**
     * Flag whether to use https or not.
     * @var boolean
     */
    var $_https;

    /**
     * Flag whether to verify HTTPS server certificates or not.
     * @var boolean
     */
    var $_httpsverify;

    /**
     * CodeIgniter instance pointer
     * @var object
     */
    var $_CI;

    /**
     * Yubikey config file
     * @var array
     */
    var $_config;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Sets up the object
     * @param    boolean $https  Flag whether to use https (optional)
     * @param    boolean $httpsverify  Flag whether to use verify HTTPS
     *                                 server certificates (optional,
     *                                 default true)
     * @access public
     */
    function __construct($configs)
    {
        $optionalDefaults = array('https' => 1, 'httpsverify' => 1);

        //set defaults
        foreach ($optionalDefaults as $n=>$v)
        {
            if (!in_array($n, $configs))
                $configs[$n] = $v;
        }

        //Load config files etc.
        $this->_CI = get_instance();
        $this->_CI->config->load('yubikey', TRUE, TRUE);
        $this->_config = $this->_CI->config->item('yubikey');

        //Set values for class

        $this->_id =  $this->_config["cid"];
        $this->_key = base64_decode($this->_config["key"]);
        $this->_https = $configs["https"];
        $this->_httpsverify = $configs["httpsverify"];
    }

    /**
     * Specify to use a different URL part for verification.
     * The default is "api.yubico.com/wsapi/verify".
     *
     * @param  string $url  New server URL part to use
     * @access public
     */
    function setURLpart($url)
    {
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * Get URL part to use for validation.
     *
     * @return string  Server URL part
     * @access public
     */
    function getURLpart()
    {
        return $this->_config["apiurl"];
    }


    /**
     * Get next URL part from list to use for validation.
     *
     * @return mixed string with URL part of false if no more URLs in list
     * @access public
     */
    function getNextURLpart()
    {
      if ($this->_url_list) $url_list=$this->_url_list;
      else $url_list=array('api.yubico.com/wsapi/2.0/verify',
                   'api2.yubico.com/wsapi/2.0/verify', 
                   'api3.yubico.com/wsapi/2.0/verify', 
                   'api4.yubico.com/wsapi/2.0/verify',
                   'api5.yubico.com/wsapi/2.0/verify');

      if ($this->_url_index>=count($url_list)) return false;
      else return $url_list[$this->_url_index++];
    }

    /**
     * Resets index to URL list
     *
     * @access public
     */
    function URLreset()
    {
      $this->_url_index=0;
    }

    /**
     * Add another URLpart.
     *
     * @access public
     */
    function addURLpart($URLpart) 
    {
      $this->_url_list[]=$URLpart;
    }

    /**
     * Return the last query sent to the server, if any.
     *
     * @return string  Request to server
     * @access public
     */
    function getLastQuery()
    {
        return $this->_lastquery;
    }

    /**
     * Return the last data received from the server, if any.
     *
     * @return string  Output from server
     * @access public
     */
    function getLastResponse()
    {
        return $this->_response;
    }

    /**
     * Parse input string into password, yubikey prefix,
     * ciphertext, and OTP.
     *
     * @param  string    Input string to parse
     * @param  string    Optional delimiter re-class, default is '[:]'
     * @return array     Keyed array with fields
     * @access public
     */
    function parsePasswordOTP($str, $delim = '[:]')
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^((.*)" . $delim . ")?" .
                "(([cbdefghijklnrtuvCBDEFGHIJKLNRTUV]{0,16})" .
                "([cbdefghijklnrtuvCBDEFGHIJKLNRTUV]{32}))$/",
                $str, $matches)) {
            return false;
        }
        $ret['password'] = $matches[2];
        $ret['otp'] = $matches[3];
        $ret['prefix'] = $matches[4];
        $ret['ciphertext'] = $matches[5];
        return $ret;
    }

    /* TODO? Add functions to get parsed parts of server response? */

    /**
     * Parse parameters from last response
     *
     * example: getParameters("timestamp", "sessioncounter", "sessionuse");
     *
     * @param  array @parameters  Array with strings representing
     *                            parameters to parse
     * @return array  parameter array from last response
     * @access public
     */
    function getParameters($parameters)
    {
      if ($parameters == null) {
        $parameters = array('timestamp', 'sessioncounter', 'sessionuse');
      }
      $param_array = array();
      foreach ($parameters as $param) {
        if(!preg_match("/" . $param . "=([0-9]+)/", $this->_response, $out)) {
          return FALSE; //PEAR::raiseError('Could not parse parameter ' . $param . ' from response');
        }
        $param_array[$param]=$out[1];
      }
      return $param_array;
    }

    /**
     * Verify Yubico OTP against multiple URLs
     * Protocol specification 2.0 is used to construct validation requests
     *
     * @param string $token        Yubico OTP
     * @param int $use_timestamp   1=>send request with &timestamp=1 to
     *                             get timestamp and session information
     *                             in the response
     * @param boolean $wait_for_all  If true, wait until all
     *                               servers responds (for debugging)
     * @param string $sl           Sync level in percentage between 0
     *                             and 100 or "fast" or "secure".
     * @param int $timeout         Max number of seconds to wait
     *                             for responses
     * @return mixed               PEAR error on error, true otherwise
     * @access public
     */
    function verify($token, $use_timestamp=null, $wait_for_all=False,
            $sl=null, $timeout=null)
    {
      /* Construct parameters string */
      $ret = $this->parsePasswordOTP($token);
      if (!$ret) {
        return FALSE; //Could not parse Yubikey OTP
      }
      $params = array('id'=>$this->_id, 
              'otp'=>$ret['otp'],
              'nonce'=>md5(uniqid(rand())));
      /* Take care of protocol version 2 parameters */
      if ($use_timestamp) $params['timestamp'] = 1;
      if ($sl) $params['sl'] = $sl;
      if ($timeout) $params['timeout'] = $timeout;
      ksort($params);
      $parameters = '';
      foreach($params as $p=>$v) $parameters .= "&" . $p . "=" . $v;
      $parameters = ltrim($parameters, "&");

      /* Generate signature. */
      if($this->_key <> "") {
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $parameters,
                         $this->_key, true));
        $signature = preg_replace('/\+/', '%2B', $signature);
        $parameters .= '&h=' . $signature;
      }

      /* Generate and prepare request. */
      $this->_lastquery=null;
      $this->URLreset();
      $mh = curl_multi_init();
      $ch = array();
      while($URLpart=$this->getNextURLpart()) 
        {
          /* Support https. */
          if ($this->_https) {
        $query = "https://";
          } else {
        $query = "http://";
          }
          $query .= $URLpart . "?" . $parameters;

          if ($this->_lastquery) { $this->_lastquery .= " "; }
          $this->_lastquery .= $query;

          $handle = curl_init($query);
          curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "PEAR Auth_Yubico");
          curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          if (!$this->_httpsverify) {
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
          }
          curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
          /* If timeout is set, we better apply it here as well
             in case the validation server fails to follow it. 
          */ 
          if ($timeout) curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
          curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $handle);

          $ch[$handle] = $handle;
        }

      /* Execute and read request. */
      $this->_response=null;
      $replay=False;
      $valid=False;
      do {
        /* Let curl do its work. */
        while (($mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active))
           == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM)
          ;

        while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) {
          if ($info['result'] == CURLE_OK) {

        /* We have a complete response from one server. */

        $str = curl_multi_getcontent($info['handle']);
        $cinfo = curl_getinfo ($info['handle']);

        if ($wait_for_all) { # Better debug info
          $this->_response .= 'URL=' . $cinfo['url'] ."\n"
            . $str . "\n";
        }

        if (preg_match("/status=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/", $str, $out)) {
          $status = $out[1];

          /* 
           * There are 3 cases.
           *
           * 1. OTP or Nonce values doesn't match - ignore
           * response.
           *
           * 2. We have a HMAC key.  If signature is invalid -
           * ignore response.  Return if status=OK or
           * status=REPLAYED_OTP.
           *
           * 3. Return if status=OK or status=REPLAYED_OTP.
           */
          if (!preg_match("/otp=".$params['otp']."/", $str) ||
              !preg_match("/nonce=".$params['nonce']."/", $str)) {
            /* Case 1. Ignore response. */
          } 
          elseif ($this->_key <> "") {
            /* Case 2. Verify signature first */
            $rows = explode("\r\n", $str);
            $response=array();
            while (list($key, $val) = each($rows)) {
              /* = is also used in BASE64 encoding so we only replace the first = by # which is not used in BASE64 */
              $val = preg_replace('/=/', '#', $val, 1);
              $row = explode("#", $val);

              if (empty($row[0]) && !isset($row[1]))
                continue; //weird bug, this fixes it.
              $response[$row[0]] = $row[1];
            }

            $parameters=array('nonce','otp', 'sessioncounter', 'sessionuse', 'sl', 'status', 't', 'timeout', 'timestamp');
            sort($parameters);
            $check=Null;
            foreach ($parameters as $param) {
              if (isset($response[$param]) && $response[$param]!=null) {
            if ($check) $check = $check . '&';
            $check = $check . $param . '=' . $response[$param];
              }
            }

            $checksignature =
              base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', utf8_encode($check),
                          $this->_key, true));

            if($response["h"] == $checksignature) {
              if ($status == 'REPLAYED_OTP') {
            if (!$wait_for_all) { $this->_response = $str; }
            $replay=True;
              } 
              if ($status == 'OK') {
            if (!$wait_for_all) { $this->_response = $str; }
            $valid=True;
              }
            }
          } else {
            /* Case 3. We check the status directly */
            if ($status == 'REPLAYED_OTP') {
              if (!$wait_for_all) { $this->_response = $str; }
              $replay=True;
            } 
            if ($status == 'OK') {
              if (!$wait_for_all) { $this->_response = $str; }
              $valid=True;
            }
          }
        }
        if (!$wait_for_all && ($valid || $replay)) 
          {
            /* We have status=OK or status=REPLAYED_OTP, return. */
            foreach ($ch as $h) {
              curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $h);
              curl_close($h);
            }
            curl_multi_close($mh);
            if ($replay) return FALSE; //REPLAYED_OTP
            if ($valid) return true;
            return FALSE; //PEAR::raiseError($status);
          }

        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $info['handle']);
        curl_close($info['handle']);
        unset ($ch[$info['handle']]);
          }
          curl_multi_select($mh);
        }
      } while ($active);

      /* Typically this is only reached for wait_for_all=true or
       * when the timeout is reached and there is no
       * OK/REPLAYED_REQUEST answer (think firewall).
       */

      foreach ($ch as $h) {
        curl_multi_remove_handle ($mh, $h);
        curl_close ($h);
      }
      curl_multi_close ($mh);

      if ($replay) return FALSE; //PEAR::raiseError('REPLAYED_OTP');
      if ($valid) return true;
      return FALSE; //PEAR::raiseError('NO_VALID_ANSWER');
    }
}
?>
```

`config/yubikey.php`

```
<?php
// Goto https://upgrade.yubico.com/getapikey/ to get below values
$config["cid"] = "";
$config["key"] = "";

$config["apiurl"] = "api.yubico.com/wsapi/verify";
?>
```

(an example)
`controllers/verifyYubikey.php`

```
class verifyyubikey extends CI_Controller
{
    function index ()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');

        echo form_open(current_url());
        echo form_input('key');
        //echo form_submit('Submit', 'submit');
        echo form_close();

        $this->load->library('yubikey', array());

        $pkey = $this->yubikey->parsePasswordOTP($this->input->post('key'));
        $pkey = $pkey["prefix"];

        $out = $this->yubikey->verify($this->input->post('key'));

        echo ($out && $pkey == "someSavedPrefix")?"Verified":"Not valid";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a Yubikey myself and found this to be very helpful and clutter free:

http://code.google.com/p/yubikey-php-webservice-class/downloads/detail?name=yubikeyPHPclass-0.96.tar.bz2&can=2&q=

Download that and have a read. It requires PHP 5 and that was the only problem I had as my server is running v4 at the moment, not a big hassle though as I just temporarily housed the actual Yubi code from the .RAR file on a PHP 5 server and pointed to it for validation.

In my own code all I need to do in files that require a user to be logged in is include this at the top of the PHP file :

```
include  "yubisession.php";
```

It then creates a session once a Yubikey has been authenticated and the key'd actual ID is one I accept so future scrips running see the set session and allow access.

The "yubisession.php" file has this inside - again just for you to view, it would requrire recoding if you wanted it to work right off the bat:

```
$yubiuser       = "cccccccvvdkd";                               //  Yubikey User ID
$yubichkurl     = "http://www.pathto/yubicheck.php";                        //  Where the PHP 5 checker is
$callingpage        = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];           //  So we know where to go back to
session_start();
if($_SESSION['yubiok'] !== $yubiuser) {                                 //  If SESSION NOT Set
    if ($_POST['yubiok'] == $yubiuser)                              //  If SESSION NOT set Check if POST = user
        {
            $_SESSION['yubiok']     = $yubiuser;                            //  If SESSION NOT Set and POST DOES = user, set session =
            header("Location: $callingpage");                           //  Direct back into the script with the SESSION now set
        ob_end_flush();
        exit();
    }   
?>
...login yubikey stuff here that StackOverflow DOESNT like displaying...
<?
exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, though it isn't codeigniter specific, it would be easy to modify.